# temporary bookmarks to quickly navigate large pdf documents

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

I have a large pdf document. There is a large bookmarks structure in the form of a table of contents. It's helpful and I don't want to mess it.

During reading, I am constantly switching between 4 or 5 specific places, which change let's say once a few hours (depending on reading speed). The document, by its nature, requires such cross-section reading all the time. These are, for example: the text currently read (in progress), the reference text on page 455, table on page 350, a drawing on page 200.

What I'd need is a very quick way to go to these places. Navigating the big bookmarks structure is a very slow option (it takes time to find specific chapter and subchapter and then scroll to a specific page). As mentioned above, I don't want to accidentally mess the structured bookmarks with table of contents.

Currently I am using Ctrl-G to go to specific page and using a pen and paper to write down page numbers currently needed and have them in front of my computer. Perhaps using a set of flat, temporary "quick bookmarks" would be a more comfortable solution. Like e.g. Ctrl+1 go to "quick bookmark 1", Ctrl-2 go to "quick bookmark 2", etc. And of course a way to instantly edit those quick bookmarks, because they change often, like Ctrl-Shift-1 make quick bookmark 1 at current place, etc. 10 "quick bookmarks" would be more than enough. Is there any method to achieve such quick navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sumatra PDF](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org) is a free PDF, eBook (ePub, Mobi), XPS, DjVu, CHM, Comic Book (CBZ and CBR) reader for Windows that is available in both installed and portable versions.

It has a *Favorites* feature that seems suited to your needs. The Favorites sidebar can even be displayed along with the Bookmarks sidebar if you want. The database is independent of your PDFs so that even when you close the files you can still view all your Favorite pages for each file and jump to the desired one directly.

Comment: This is what I needed. The only thing I noticed is that Foxit has slightly better rendering, or contrast. Never thought of it before. But the idea of Favorites in Sumatra is very useful for my purpose (I created an autohotkey macro for the keyboard shortcuts).

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575613/pdf-viewer-with-portable-bookmarks-like-foxit-reader-under-windows) claims that [Foxit reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/) has the ability to place user bookmarks in PDF documents. It is available for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: My question is about placing my own bookmarks, each accesible by a keyboard shortcut, that would not mess the main bookmark structure with table of contents. Portability is not an issue for me.